# Найти 3 строки с самым большим соотношениям 2-х переменных в map<String, Class>

Tags: java, map

Нужно найти 3 животных с самый большим соотношениям (dreaming к total_sleep) и указать это в процентах((dreaming/total_sleep)*100). При этом игнорировать все значение где есть 0. Игнорирования всех записей где есть 0 уже написано, но дальше ничего не получается.

Есть Map<String, Animal> в котором Animal это класс

```
    package com.company;

public class Animal {
    public double body_wt;
    public double brain_wt;
    public double non_dreaming;
    public double dreaming;
    public double total_sleep;
    public double life_span;
    public double gestation;
    public int predation;
    public int exposure;
    public int danger;

    public void setBody_wt(double body_wt) {
        this.body_wt = body_wt;
    }

    public void setBrain_wt(double brain_wt) {
        this.brain_wt = brain_wt;
    }

    public void setNon_dreaming(double non_dreaming) {
        this.non_dreaming = non_dreaming;
    }

    public void setDreaming(double dreaming) {
        this.dreaming = dreaming;
    }

    public void setTotal_sleep(double total_sleep) {
        this.total_sleep = total_sleep;
    }

    public void setLife_span(double life_span) {
        this.life_span = life_span;
    }

    public void setGestation(double gestation) {
        this.gestation = gestation;
    }

    public void setPredation(int predation) {
        this.predation = predation;
    }

    public void setExposure(int exposure) {
        this.exposure = exposure;
    }

    public void setDanger(int danger) {
        this.danger = danger;
    }

    public double getBrain_wt() {
        return brain_wt;
    }

    public double getBody_wt() {
        return body_wt;
    }

    public double getDreaming() {
        return dreaming;
    }

    public double getGestation() {
        return gestation;
    }

    public double getLife_span() {
        return life_span;
    }

    public double getNon_dreaming() {
        return non_dreaming;
    }

    public double getTotal_sleep() {
        return total_sleep;
    }

    public int getDanger() {
        return danger;
    }

    public int getExposure() {
        return exposure;
    }

    public int getPredation() {
        return predation;
    }

    private String getValue(double value){
        return value == 0? "unknown": String.valueOf(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {

        return "AnimalCharacteristics{bodyWt="+getValue(body_wt)+", brainWt="+getValue(brain_wt)+", nonDreaming=" +
                getValue(non_dreaming)+ ", dreaming="+ getValue(dreaming)+ ", totalSleep="+getValue(total_sleep)+
                ", lifeSpan="+getValue(life_span)+", gestation="+ getValue(gestation)+", predation="+predation+", exposure="+exposure+", danger="+danger+"}";
    }

}
```

И также Main в котором в public static void Task2(Map<String,Animal> map) есть все мои попытки сделать это задание. (species это ключ к map)

```
package com.company;

import com.sun.jdi.Value;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.lang.Double.*;

public class Main {

    public static Map<String, Animal> readAnimals(){
        Map<String, Animal> animals = new HashMap <>();
        Scanner devScanner = null;
        try {
            devScanner = new Scanner(new File("mammals.txt"));

            String species = "q";
            devScanner.nextLine();
            while (devScanner.hasNext()) {
                Animal animal = new Animal();
                String nextLine = devScanner.nextLine();
                String[] anData = nextLine.split(";");
                for (int i = 0; i < anData.length; i++) {
                    if (anData[i].isEmpty()) continue;
                    switch(i){
                        case 0:  species = anData[0];continue;
                        case 1: if(anData[1].equals("NA")){animal.setBody_wt(0);} else{ animal.setBody_wt(Double.parseDouble(anData[1]));} continue;
                        case 2: if(anData[2].equals("NA")){animal.setBrain_wt(0);} else{ animal.setBrain_wt(Double.parseDouble(anData[2]));} continue;
                        case 3: if(anData[3].equals("NA")){animal.setNon_dreaming(0);} else{ animal.setNon_dreaming(Double.parseDouble(anData[3]));} continue;
                        case 4: if(anData[4].equals("NA")){animal.setDreaming(0);} else{ animal.setDreaming(Double.parseDouble(anData[4]));} continue;
                        case 5: if(anData[5].equals("NA")){animal.setTotal_sleep(0);} else{ animal.setTotal_sleep(Double.parseDouble(anData[5]));} continue;
                        case 6: if(anData[6].equals("NA")){animal.setLife_span(0);} else{ animal.setLife_span(Double.parseDouble(anData[6]));} continue;
                        case 7: if(anData[7].equals("NA")){animal.setGestation(0);} else{ animal.setGestation(Double.parseDouble(anData[7]));} continue;
                        case 8: if(anData[8].equals("NA")){animal.setPredation(0);} else { animal.setPredation(Integer.parseInt(anData[8]));} continue;
                        case 9: if(anData[9].equals("NA")){animal.setExposure(0);} else { animal.setExposure(Integer.parseInt(anData[9]));} continue;
                        case 10: if(anData[10].equals("NA")){animal.setDanger(0);} else { animal.setDanger(Integer.parseInt(anData[10]));} break;
                    }
                }
                animals.put(species, animal);
            }



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return animals;
    }

    public static void Task1(Map<String, Animal> map)
    {
        System.out.println(map.values().stream().max(Comparator.comparingDouble(Animal::getBody_wt)));
    }

//    public static <K, E, C extends Collection<E>> E removeOne(Map<K, C> map, K key) {
//        C col = map.get(key);
//        Iterator<E> it = col.iterator();
//        E e = it.next();
//        it.remove();
//        if (!it.hasNext()) {
//            map.remove(key);
//        }
//        return e;
//    }

//    public static String removeOne(Map<String, Animal map, int key) {
//        return map.get(key).size() == 1 ? map.remove(key).pop() : map.get(key).pop();
//    }
//
    public static void Task2(Map<String,Animal> map)
    {
        List entryList = new ArrayList();
        //Map<String, Animal> map2 = map.values().parallelStream().filter(x -> x.equals(0)).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> String.valueOf(x)));
       // Map<String, Animal> map2 = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),Animal::))
        entryList = map.values().stream().filter(s->s.body_wt!=0 && s.brain_wt!=0&& s.non_dreaming!=0
        && s.dreaming!=0 && s.total_sleep!=0 && s.life_span!=0 && s.gestation!=0 && s.predation!=0 && s.exposure!=0 &&
                s.danger!=0).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(entryList);
        List q = new ArrayList();
//        q = map.values().stream().filter(s->s.body_wt!=0 && s.brain_wt!=0&& s.non_dreaming!=0
//                && s.dreaming!=0 && s.total_sleep!=0 && s.life_span!=0 && s.gestation!=0 && s.predation!=0 && s.exposure!=0 &&
//                s.danger!=0 &&).acollect(Collectors.toList());
//       // q.forEach(n -> (n.));
//        map.values().forEach(Animal::getDreaming);
    }



    public static void Task4(Map<String, Animal> map)
    {
       // HashMap<String,Animal> map2 = new HashMap<String, Animal>();
        //ValueComparator bvc = new ValueComparator(map);
        List entryList = new ArrayList(map.entrySet());




      System.out.println(entryList);

       // List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>((Collection<? extends Value>) new TreeMap<String, Animal>( map ));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        Map<String, Animal> map = readAnimals();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Animal>> itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Animal> entry =  itr.next();
            // get key
            String key = entry.getKey();
            // get value
            Animal value = entry.getValue();
           System.out.println(value.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Task 1");
        Task1(readAnimals());
        System.out.println("Task 2");
        Task2(readAnimals());
        System.out.println("Task 4");
        Task4(readAnimals());
    }
}
```

И сам текстовый файл (mammals.txt)

```
species;body_wt;brain_wt;non_dreaming;dreaming;total_sleep;life_span;gestation;predation;exposure;danger
Africanelephant;6654;5712;NA;NA;3.3;38.6;645;3;5;3
Africangiantpouchedrat;1;6.6;6.3;2;8.3;4.5;42;3;1;3
ArcticFox;3.385;44.5;NA;NA;12.5;14;60;1;1;1
Arcticgroundsquirrel;0.92;5.7;NA;NA;16.5;NA;25;5;2;3
Asianelephant;2547;4603;2.1;1.8;3.9;69;624;3;5;4
Baboon;10.55;179.5;9.1;0.7;9.8;27;180;4;4;4
Bigbrownbat;0.023;0.3;15.8;3.9;19.7;19;35;1;1;1
Braziliantapir;160;169;5.2;1;6.2;30.4;392;4;5;4
Cat;3.3;25.6;10.9;3.6;14.5;28;63;1;2;1
Chimpanzee;52.16;440;8.3;1.4;9.7;50;230;1;1;1
Chinchilla;0.425;6.4;11;1.5;12.5;7;112;5;4;4
Cow;465;423;3.2;0.7;3.9;30;281;5;5;5
Deserthedgehog;0.55;2.4;7.6;2.7;10.3;NA;NA;2;1;2
Donkey;187.1;419;NA;NA;3.1;40;365;5;5;5
EasternAmericanmole;0.075;1.2;6.3;2.1;8.4;3.5;42;1;1;1
Echidna;3;25;8.6;0;8.6;50;28;2;2;2
Europeanhedgehog;0.785;3.5;6.6;4.1;10.7;6;42;2;2;2
Galago;0.2;5;9.5;1.2;10.7;10.4;120;2;2;2
Genet;1.41;17.5;4.8;1.3;6.1;34;NA;1;2;1
Giantarmadillo;60;81;12;6.1;18.1;7;NA;1;1;1
Giraffe;529;680;NA;0.3;NA;28;400;5;5;5
Goat;27.66;115;3.3;0.5;3.8;20;148;5;5;5
Goldenhamster;0.12;1;11;3.4;14.4;3.9;16;3;1;2
Gorilla;207;406;NA;NA;12;39.3;252;1;4;1
Grayseal;85;325;4.7;1.5;6.2;41;310;1;3;1
Graywolf;36.33;119.5;NA;NA;13;16.2;63;1;1;1
Groundsquirrel;0.101;4;10.4;3.4;13.8;9;28;5;1;3
Guineapig;1.04;5.5;7.4;0.8;8.2;7.6;68;5;3;4
Horse;521;655;2.1;0.8;2.9;46;336;5;5;5
Jaguar;100;157;NA;NA;10.8;22.4;100;1;1;1
Kangaroo;35;56;NA;NA;NA;16.3;33;3;5;4
Lessershort-tailedshrew;0.005;0.14;7.7;1.4;9.1;2.6;21.5;5;2;4
Littlebrownbat;0.01;0.25;17.9;2;19.9;24;50;1;1;1
Man;62;1320;6.1;1.9;8;100;267;1;1;1
Molerat;0.122;3;8.2;2.4;10.6;NA;30;2;1;1
Mountainbeaver;1.35;8.1;8.4;2.8;11.2;NA;45;3;1;3
Mouse;0.023;0.4;11.9;1.3;13.2;3.2;19;4;1;3
Muskshrew;0.048;0.33;10.8;2;12.8;2;30;4;1;3
NAmericanopossum;1.7;6.3;13.8;5.6;19.4;5;12;2;1;1
Nine-bandedarmadillo;3.5;10.8;14.3;3.1;17.4;6.5;120;2;1;1
Okapi;250;490;NA;1;NA;23.6;440;5;5;5
Owlmonkey;0.48;15.5;15.2;1.8;17;12;140;2;2;2
Patasmonkey;10;115;10;0.9;10.9;20.2;170;4;4;4
Phanlanger;1.62;11.4;11.9;1.8;13.7;13;17;2;1;2
Pig;192;180;6.5;1.9;8.4;27;115;4;4;4
Rabbit;2.5;12.1;7.5;0.9;8.4;18;31;5;5;5
Raccoon;4.288;39.2;NA;NA;12.5;13.7;63;2;2;2
Rat;0.28;1.9;10.6;2.6;13.2;4.7;21;3;1;3
Redfox;4.235;50.4;7.4;2.4;9.8;9.8;52;1;1;1
Rhesusmonkey;6.8;179;8.4;1.2;9.6;29;164;2;3;2
Rockhyrax(Heterob);0.75;12.3;5.7;0.9;6.6;7;225;2;2;2
Rockhyrax(Procaviahab);3.6;21;4.9;0.5;5.4;6;225;3;2;3
Roedeer;14.83;98.2;NA;NA;2.6;17;150;5;5;5
Sheep;55.5;175;3.2;0.6;3.8;20;151;5;5;5
Slowloris;1.4;12.5;NA;NA;11;12.7;90;2;2;2
Starnosedmole;0.06;1;8.1;2.2;10.3;3.5;NA;3;1;2
Tenrec;0.9;2.6;11;2.3;13.3;4.5;60;2;1;2
Treehyrax;2;12.3;4.9;0.5;5.4;7.5;200;3;1;3
Treeshrew;0.104;2.5;13.2;2.6;15.8;2.3;46;3;2;2
Vervet;4.19;58;9.7;0.6;10.3;24;210;4;3;4
Wateropossum;3.5;3.9;12.8;6.6;19.4;3;14;2;1;1
Yellow-belliedmarmot;4.05;17;NA;NA;NA;13;38;3;1;1
```

Comment: Что у вас конкретно не получается ?

Comment: @PerfectVoyage не могу найти само соотношение (и через это и процент и посортировать). Просто не получается использовать именно эти переменные

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде того:

```
public static void Task2(Map<String, Animal> map) {
    List<Map.Entry<String, Animal>> animals =
            map.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(e -> Objects.nonNull(e.getValue()))
                    .filter(e -> e.getValue().getDreaming() > 0)
                    .filter(e -> e.getValue().getTotal_sleep() > 0)
                    .sorted(
                            Comparator.<Map.Entry<String, Animal>>comparingDouble(
                                    e -> (e.getValue().getDreaming() / e.getValue().getTotal_sleep()) * 100
                            ).reversed())
                    .limit(3)
                    .collect(toList());
    System.out.println(animals);
}
```

Результат:

```
[Asianelephant=AnimalCharacteristics{bodyWt=2547.0, brainWt=4603.0, nonDreaming=2.1, dreaming=1.8, totalSleep=3.9, lifeSpan=69.0, gestation=624.0, predation=3, exposure=5, danger=4}, Europeanhedgehog=AnimalCharacteristics{bodyWt=0.785, brainWt=3.5, nonDreaming=6.6, dreaming=4.1, totalSleep=10.7, lifeSpan=6.0, gestation=42.0, predation=2, exposure=2, danger=2}, Wateropossum=AnimalCharacteristics{bodyWt=3.5, brainWt=3.9, nonDreaming=12.8, dreaming=6.6, totalSleep=19.4, lifeSpan=3.0, gestation=14.0, predation=2, exposure=1, danger=1}]
[AnimalCharacteristics{bodyWt=2547.0, brainWt=4603.0, nonDreaming=2.1, dreaming=1.8, totalSleep=3.9, lifeSpan=69.0, gestation=624.0, predation=3, exposure=5, danger=4}, AnimalCharacteristics{bodyWt=0.785, brainWt=3.5, nonDreaming=6.6, dreaming=4.1, totalSleep=10.7, lifeSpan=6.0, gestation=42.0, predation=2, exposure=2, danger=2}, AnimalCharacteristics{bodyWt=3.5, brainWt=3.9, nonDreaming=12.8, dreaming=6.6, totalSleep=19.4, lifeSpan=3.0, gestation=14.0, predation=2, exposure=1, danger=1}]
```

В случае, если нам не нужны `java.util.Map.Entry`, а нужен просто список `com.company.Animal`, то чуть проще:

```
public static void Task2(Map<String, Animal> map) {
    List<Animal> animals =
            map.values().stream()
                    .filter(a -> a.getDreaming() > 0)
                    .filter(a -> a.getTotal_sleep() > 0)
                    .sorted(
                            Comparator.<Animal>comparingDouble(
                                    a -> (a.getDreaming() / a.getTotal_sleep()) * 100
                            ).reversed())
                    .limit(3)
                    .collect(toList());
    System.out.println(animals);
}
```